# submit doesn't work in form with multiple inputs without button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I found a strange behavior and I can't explain it. My question is if following behavior is a bug or is it documented.

In the following 3 forms only two can be submitted **on press enter**. The first form doesn't submit on enter key. Why?

```js
function onSubmit() {
    alert('Submit');
}
```

```html
 First:
 <form onsubmit="onSubmit(); event.preventDefault()">
     <input />
     <input />
 </form>
 Second:
 <form onsubmit="onSubmit(); event.preventDefault()">
     <input />
 </form>
 Third:
 <form onsubmit="onSubmit(); event.preventDefault()">
     <input />
     <input />
     <button></button>
 </form>
```

A form with only one input works. A form with a button works. But a form with two inputs without buttons doesn't work.

Comment: I think that it is HTML related. Please try to add a `<button type="submit">`, even if it is hidden

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I think you could be on right path but the second form doesn't have a button and works. The third form has two inputs and a button (without `type="submit"`) and works. Why? I'll try it without Angular.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I tried it and it's completely unrelated to Angular. Thank you very much. I'll change the question.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks. The second dupe contains the answer. It's documented in HTML 2.0.

Comment: just add <form onsubmit="onSubmit()"> don't forget parntesis

Comment: @HiDd3N That doesn't answer the question. The question is, why the first form isn't submitted but the other two forms are submitted on pressing enter. But the answer is in the second dupe.